# Append Excel columns with XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet, and I want to selectively transfer its content to a list. The object has 2 attributes, `String id, String str`.

I want to set the first column as id. I got this part right. I also want to append the values of column 3,4,6,7. For example, if my excel looks like:

```
4404A01459C1    || A1 || 13 || 14 || B1 || 8 || 7
```

I want 4404A01459C1 as id(again, I got this part). Then I want 13;14;8;7, skipping A1 and B1, separating the values with ; How do I achieve this?

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\work\\calculatepi\\test.xlsx");
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    List<SampleGene> sgl=new ArrayList<SampleGene>();

    while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
        Row row  = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        SampleGene sg = new SampleGene();
        sg.setId(row.getCell(0).toString());
        //need help here

        sgl.add(sg);
    }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using StringBuilder and iterate over cellIterator;append each cell value to the StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(cellIterator.hasNext())
{
sb.append(cellIterator.next().toString());
sb.append(";");
}
sg.setStr(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. However, I didn't use the cellIterator since I'm using the columns selectively

Comment: In that case, you can use `for` loop and skip the columns(if you know their index) which you don't want. Or in Iterator, get Cell using `.next()` and use `getColumnIndex()` method in Cell and skip them.